# how to configure oracle database in ATOM for the django development?

Tags: python, django, oracle

I got the Error is This:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, testapp
Running migrations:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sandeepreddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\sandeepreddy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 506, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword
```

Comment: I have configured oracle like this 

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'orcl',
        'USER': 'krishna',
        'PASSWORD': 'oracle',
        'HOST':  'localhost',
        'PORT': 1521,
    }
}

Comment: Plese show your code